# Scene2d Stage Actor setup issues

Tags: android, libgdx, scene-graph, scene2d

I am creating a game using libgdx.

In the same each level has a class. I have stage as a member variable of the class. To this stage, I add actors.

Inside the levels class, I have attaced the input processor to the stage like below.

```
stage = new Stage();
sviewPort = new StretchViewport(OSR_Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, OSR_Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(OSR_Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, OSR_Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
camera.update();
sviewPort.setCamera(camera);
stage.setViewport(sviewPort);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

The level object is instantiated in another class known as GameScreen. GameScreen implements the Screen interface.

I am unable to detect touch events on my actors in the stage. Each actor has also been given bounds as per the world coordinates. I have added the following code on each actor to detect touch

```
this.addListener(new InputListener(){
     public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
          System.out.println("touchdown at " + x + " " + y);
          return true;
      }
  });
```

Comment: You should disable InputProcessor on Stage when it is not required to kick start your Actor's InputProcessor. Use Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);

Comment: Really late to answer this, but I just want to give a suggestion to make sure to call `stage.draw()` and `stage.act()` methods in `render()`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create new InputListener, but you need to use one that you register in Gdx.input.setInputProcessor

```
this.addListener(stage)
```

Didn't test.

Comment: every actor can have their own inputlistener to handle touch events differently

Comment: but if you create new InputListener, you need to register it on "Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(input_listener);" without it you don't get event to this listener.